# Efficient way to calculate Mode of an mcmc.list object in R or How to convert a mcmc.list to a ff data type? (Handling Big data of type mcmc.list)

Tags: r, jags, ff

In R, I am using Rjags which calls JAGS to sample for a posterior distribution, which returns the samples in  mcmc.list form. My aim is to take the Mode of each sampled variable(of the first chain) present in the mcmc.list form.

When I load the mcmc.list object file, it consumes 8 out of 24GB of RAM I have access to. Further, when I use the below mentioned method to calculate its Mode, the RAM crosses the 23GB mark and the process crashes.

I believe there are better and more efficient ways to do this, so if someone can throw some light.

The method I use to generate the Mode is given below. Here samples[[1]] is the first chain of the mcmc.list

```
Mode<-lapply(samples[[1]], function(x){ ux <- unique(x)
  ux[which.max(tabulate(match(x, ux)))]})
```

I was also looking at the ff package because the above example is only for half of my dataset. I cannot understand how to convert the mcmc.list to ff type data frame `sample<-as.ffdf(samples[[1]])` takes forever to run.

If anyone can provide some resources explaining the ff package in detail with example, that would be great too. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

If the issue is just computational I would suggest thinning the chain so that the output is not so large.  There is a `thin` argument in the `jags.samples` function that you could use to decrease the output size.

Conversely, you could try converting the samples into a matrix.  This would require the `coda` package.

```
samples_matrix <- as.matrix(samples, chains = TRUE)
```

This way you could calculate the mode of smaller portions of the posterior.

Comment: I am using 20000 samples. How much do you recommend I thin ? I have been using n.thin=3 so far.

Comment: Currently your output is ~ 8 GB and you are thinning by 3, which is causing computational issues.  You don't want to thin so much so that you do not have many samples from your posterior, but you should thin enough such that you can summarize it.  I'd recommend thinning by 5 or 6, which should hopefully decrease the size of your output.